# How to find time of different countries?

Tags: asp.net

How to find time of different countries? I want to find time of below mentioned countries.
Brazzaville
Chad
Gabon
DRC
Kenya
Tanzania
Uganda
Rwanda
Nigeria
Ghana
Zambia

Time Zone of Tanzania is "East Africa Time Zone (UTC+03:00)". So how to calculate time from Time Zone "UTC+03:00".
I did Like this, but giving error.

```
string zoneId2 = "East Africa Time";
TimeZoneInfo tzi2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId2);
DateTime result2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(System.DateTime.UtcNow, tzi2);
DateTime.Text = "Time is " + result2 + " in Tanzania ";
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=593

Answer (score 1):

The timezone Id which you are passing is not current. "East Africa Time" is understood my .Net class is "E. Africa Standard Time"

Refer this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx

It should be exact name as expected by .net class.

```
string zoneId2 = "E. Africa Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo tzi2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId2);
DateTime result2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(System.DateTime.UtcNow, tzi2);
Console.WriteLine("Time is " + result2 + " in Tanzania ");
Console.ReadLine();
```